# Optimizing Reddit Data Scrape using Python + PRAW library

Tags: python, optimization, praw

I'm writing a script to scrape the subreddit "Am I The Asshole" and generate a set of inputs/labels in order to train a NN to read a post and predict whether or not reddit will consider the user the asshole or not the asshole (choosing to ignore more grey area labels such as ESH and NAH for now, although if I get a full NN training cycle established including those labels in the scraping and training should be trivial)

In order to reproduce this code you'll need to make your own praw point of contact, I used [this geeks for geeks post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scraping-reddit-using-python/) as a guide. Should take about 5 minutes to set up.

The desired output would look something like:

`{body of the original post: (text), label: (NTA/YTA), some way to find the original post: URL + ID}`

in a CSV, 1 data point per line.

I'm using the top comment (comment 0 is always a bot pinned comment) as the label, but throwing the point away if it doesn't contain NTA/YTA in the text since doing sentiment analysis is outside of the scope of this little project.

```
import praw
import pandas as pd
import re

# Read-only instance
# ========== PUT YOUR DETAILS HERE (see g4g post linked above) ========== 
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id="",                            # your client id
                     client_secret="",      # your client secret
                     user_agent="",                             # your user agent
                     check_for_async=False)       
# =======================================================================
 
subreddit = reddit.subreddit("AmITheAsshole")

# Scraping the top 500 posts of all time
posts = subreddit.top(time_filter="all", limit=500)
 
posts_dict = {"Post Text": [], "Label" : [],
              "ID": [], "Post URL": []
              }
 
for post in posts:
    if len(post.comments) >= 2:
      top_comment = post.comments[1].body

      # probably a better way to do this, but this works sooooo...
      nta_label = re.search("NTA", top_comment)
      yta_label = re.search("YTA", top_comment)
      label = ""

      if nta_label != None:
        label = "nta"
      elif yta_label != None:
        label = "yta"

      # check that top comment includes a label, else skip
      if label != "":
        # Text inside a post
        posts_dict["Post Text"].append(post.selftext)

        # Label associated with top comment
        posts_dict["Label"].append(label)
        
        # Unique ID of post
        posts_dict["ID"].append(post.id)
        
        # URL of post
        posts_dict["Post URL"].append(post.url)
 
# Saving the data in a pandas dataframe + exporting it
top_posts = pd.DataFrame(posts_dict)
top_posts.to_csv("Posts.csv", index=True)
```

My main issue is that this code takes a while to run (~1 hour for 500 posts), and I need many thousands of data points. If push comes to shove I can make what I have work, but it isn't ideal. Especially if I encounter issues and need much more data than originally expected. As of right now, the script is quite unoptimized as I'm not terribly familiar with the nicher side of Python that I think could speed this up.

Can someone let me know how to optimize this / if there are any significant optimizations to be had, or if PRAW is simply slow and I'll just have to dedicate a computer to this for the next few days?

Edit: I've timed each section for a session scraping 50 posts, here are the first 10 lines:

dump time for 50 posts was 0.01175000000000015

| post times | regex times |
| --- | --- |
| 0.25297599999999987 | 0.00012900000000004574 |
| 0.08677899999999994 | 2.0000000000131024e-05 |
| 0.08174499999999996 | 1.8000000000073513e-05 |
| 0.08257700000000012 | 1.7999999999851468e-05 |
| 0.08336699999999997 | 1.7999999999851468e-05 |
| 0.00679799999999986 | 0.0 |
| 0.07945700000000011 | 1.7999999999851468e-05 |
| 0.068473 | 1.700000000015578e-05 |
| 0.009603999999999946 | 0.0 |
| 0.08033699999999966 | 1.8000000000295557e-05 |
| 0.12934800000000024 | 1.700000000015578e-05 |
| 0.06727399999999983 | 1.6000000000016e-05 |

Seems like regex is a tiny part of the total time, and most of the time is wrapped up in post fetching, which I don't think is really accessible as far as optimization goes. Seems as though this is about as fast as it will run! Thanks

Comment: Several hours of runtime is not too bad for web crawlers. Thousands of posts is not going to take more than a day. It might actually take more than a day for you to find where the bottleneck is and optimize it, so you are better off just run it on a server, or several, if you can spread the workload manually. To answer the question, it's better for you to time different parts of the code first to find the most time-consuming part. Whether it's network I/O, regex matching or dumping will help determine which optimization we should choose.

Comment: ok! that makes sense, I just thought I might be doing something horribly wrong. I'll time the sections and post the results sometime today.